# how to install Jitsi SIP phone on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, sip, voip, jitsi

could anybody know how to install Jitsi Sip phone on ubuntu 16.04 / 64 bit. I found many packages under Jitsi downloads, but couldn't know which one to download (jicofo? or meet?, ...).

https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post http://www.4simple.org/how-install-sip-communicator-jitsi-2-8-in-ubuntu-16-04/ you just need:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

wget https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi/debian/jitsi_2.8.5426-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i jitsi_2.8*.deb
```